# setfacl broke my ubuntu installation

Tags: permissions, login, acl

I'm not 100% sure but I think I ran `setfacl` with the wrong argument and changed acl stuff for everything under(non recursively?) '/' instead of './' , immediately half the applications I had running crashed and after a restart I can't login.

When I try to login the following flashes for a split second and then it goes back to the login screen, when I try to login from terminal it's the same thing but without the error message.

[image]

I don't know much about acl or what to do, I tried restoring from a backup with timeshift (I set it to backup everything) but it didn't effect the problem.

the command might have been:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:username:r
```

or

```
sudo setfacl -m u:username:r /
```

but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact command(s) that you run to create this problem.

Comment: @SorenA i'm not 100% but i think it might have been sudo setfacl -m u:username:r /

Comment: Without knowing the exact command it's impossible to determine what's going on, but it's very likely you broke your installation, the only way to fix that is from a LIveUSB/installer image and undo that change, or reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was remove the acl entry for my uid on the root directory with:

```
setfacl -x user:<username> <base directory>
```

After doing this from another OS I was able to boot and login no problem.

Apparently it's good habit to never type ./ for the current dir because . is perfectly valid and reduces these types of mistakes.